# How to perform php Output buffering with databse data in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am performing out buffereing in a wordpress site. I developed using OOP (MVC) structure. My code for buffering section is

```
Class RPController{
 public function __construct()
 {
   add_action('wp_head', array($this,'rpl_buffer_start'));
   add_action('wp_footer', array($this,'rpl_buffer_end'));
 }
 public function rpl_buffer_start() 
 { 
    ob_start(array($this,"rpl_callback")); 
 }
 public function rpl_buffer_end() 
 { 
    ob_end_flush(); 
 } 
 public function rpl_callback($buffer)
{
$data = get_option('rpl_form_data');
if(isset($data)):
   for ($i=0; $i < count($data['rimg']); $i++) 
   {
       $buffer = str_replace($data['oimg'][$i], $data['rimg'][$i], $buffer);
    }
endif;

return $buffer;

}
}
$RPController = new RPController();
```

its not buffereing the output. 
the `data` from db is saved in the foolowing format a 2 dimetional array

```
 Array ( [oimg] => Array ( [0] => RightStyle Profile [1] => Admin Test ) [rimg] => Array ( [0] => Profile [1] => Test ) )
```

When i manually create this kind of array not from db , this buffering works perfectly fine. 
Can anyone tell me why this is not working on db data ?